# how to change the direction of X-axis label in ms charts

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, mschart

Hi I am using Ms chart control  in winforms application for displaying values according to dates

I need to change the x-axis  label values(Dates)  direction horizantal  to vertical

I have searched so many properties but i did not find any solution for this.

Any one help me on this problem

[image]

Many Thanks ....

Comment: Won't binding the data other way round do, do you really need the X axis vertical ?

Comment: @V4 Vendetta ya i really need the x-axis vertical

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As I understand your question - you are asking how to rotate the chart label to display vertically.

You can rotate the x-axis label as follows:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = -90;
```

This assumes you have associated your series with the first chart area, which is the default without modification when using the Winforms designer.

The following images shows how the chart would look before the code above is applied, the second image shows how it appears after the code is applied.

Let me know if this is not what you are trying to do and I will post an updated answer.

Before rotation
[image: Before Rotation]

After Rotation
[image]

Edit: Another answer added after my initial post mentions in certain situations it may be important to set chartArea1.AxisX.IsLabelAutoFit = false;

Answer (score 18):

If you have not already done so, get the chart samples from microsoft:
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart

Then check the section on Labels
Chart Features > Labels

To answer your question directly, set the angle in LabelStyle, and don't forget to disable autofit

```
chartArea1.AxisX.IsLabelAutoFit = false;
chartArea1.AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = 90;
```

Comment: IsLabelAutofit was overriding font size as well. Got me out of a bind. Have some points!