# Force Windows Form Chart Y Axis Label to Rotate 90 Degrees

Tags: .net, charts, visualization

I am using Windows Form Data Visualization chart to generate chart and save to images (in memory stream, to be specific).
It is required that the horizontal margins must be small. When I set the position and size of the ChartArea, the space for Y axis is small, as required. The labels are sometimes splitted into multiple lines or rotated 45 degrees, which are difficult to read. Is there a way to force them to rotate 90 degrees? The pictures are the examples.

[image: bad example]
[image: one of the axis is not desired]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After some search, I found a solution.

```
chartArea.AxisY.IsLabelAutoFit = false
chartArea.AxisY.LabelStyle.Angle = 90
```

I will leave it here in case some other people search for the same problem.

The credit goes to [another question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6739303/how-to-change-the-direction-of-x-axis-label-in-ms-charts)